# Finding grandparents in Vapor

Tags: ios, swift, vapor

I am currently using Vapor for a database and have run into a roadblock I could use some help with.

I currently have a `Business` object, which has `[AccessPoint]` children. Each `AccessPoint`, itself has a number of `[AccessPointContactMethod]`.

An `AccessPointContactMethod` can reference its parent `AccessPoint` by inspecting its `accessPointID` property which is set by Vapor when creating a parent child relationship.

In fact, I use this to make sure that when a new `AccessPointContactMethod` is created, if the parent `AccessPoint` already has a child with the same address, we abort the post request:

```
return AccessPointContactMethod.query(on: req).group(.and) { and in
            and.filter(\.contactMethodAddress == contactMethod.contactMethodAddress)
            and.filter(\.accessPointID == contactMethod.accessPointID)
            }.all()
            .flatMap(to: AccessPointContactMethod.self) { methods in
                if methods.isEmpty {
                    return contactMethod.save(on: req)
                }
                else {
                    let duplicateContactMethodStatus = HTTPResponseStatus.custom(code: 600, reasonPhrase: "Duplicate Contact Method")
                    throw Abort(duplicateContactMethodStatus)
                }
        }
```

So this leads me to the problem I'm having. At the moment, I only check if there are duplicate addresses in that one `AccessPoint`, but what I want to do is check all the `AccessPoint` objects belonging to the one `Business`, and if there is any `AccessPoint` that contains an `AccessPointContactMethod` with the same address, then we abort the request.

Therefore, it seems to me, that I need a way of getting to the `Business` grandparent object and iterating over the `[AccessPoint]` children for any duplicates.

Vapor, reactive programming, databases are all quite new to me, so I'm sure I haven't described this question wonderfully but if anyone can understand what I'm trying to do and has any ideas, I'd be highly appreciative!